# How to stack a checkbox and an icon in vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, layout, vuetify.js

I want something like this (+ is checkbox, - is remove icon):

```
+ |‾‾‾‾‾‾|
- |______|
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-col cols="12" md="6" v-for="(choice, idx) in choices" :key="idx">
        <v-text-field v-model="choice.text" outlined clearable type="text">
          <template v-slot:prepend>
              <v-col>
                <v-checkbox v-model="choice.isCorrect" hide-details />
                <v-icon color="red" left>remove_circle</v-icon>
              </v-col>
            </template>
        </v-text-field>
      </v-col>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data() {
        return {
          choices: [{
              text: "Foo",
              isCorrect: true
            },
            {
              text: "Bar",
              isCorrect: false
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you just want the layout to have them sitting beside a text area vertically or are you looking to stack one on top of the other (z-index)? Either way, you can add classes to your vue markup and then use CSS to put stuff where you want it.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've added the snippet.

Comment: @BryceHowitson 
no, not z-index stack. What would be the best way to achieve this through css? I could use margin but that would be so dirty and possibly would break which change of font-size etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly it seems better to just create a separate div for this rather than using the prepend slot, which has some weird customized margin that's not well-suited for this purpose. I've edited your code to achieve the effect that you want - https://codepen.io/CodingDeer/pen/LYPbPxr.

I've also put the snippet here but the icon is not working here for some reason.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
<v-app>
  <v-col cols="12" md="6" v-for="(choice, idx) in choices" :key="idx">
    <v-row>
      <div>
        <div>
          <v-checkbox 
            class="ma-0"
            v-model="choice.isCorrect" 
            hide-details />
        </div>
        <v-icon color="red">remove_circle</v-icon>
      </div>
      <v-text-field v-model="choice.text" outlined clearable type="text">
      </v-text-field>
    </v-row>
  </v-col>
</v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data() {
        return {
          choices: [{
              text: "Foo",
              isCorrect: true
            },
            {
              text: "Bar",
              isCorrect: false
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```